# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext

Tags: spring-mvc

I know this is a duplicate, but I've spent days working with all the solutions. I havent been able to get any to work. Can someone please take a look.

If any additional information is required, please let me know.

My Stacktrace is as follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class [ com.davis.ty.domain.Products] declared in Hibernate configuration <mapping/> entry
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
```

My servlet.xml is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.davis.ty" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My hibrenate.cfg.xml is this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.davis.ty.domain.Products" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My sessionfactory code is:

```
package com.davis.ty.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.davis.ty.domain.Products;

@Repository
public class ProductsDAOImpl implements  ProductsDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addProduct(Products products) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(products);
    }

    public void updateProduct(Products products)
     {
          sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(products);
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Products> listProducts() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Products").list();
    }

    public void removeProducts(int id) {
        Products products = (Products) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Products.class, id);
        if (null != products) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(products);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Products getProductsById(int id) {

         return (Products) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Products.class, id);

    }

}
```

My form class is as follows:

```
package com.davis.ty.domain;


    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    /**
     * Entity bean with JPA annotations
     * Hibernate provides JPA implementation
     * @author pankaj
     *
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name="products")
    public class Products {

        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name="CODE")
        private int code;

        @Column(name="Dept")
        private int dept;

        @Column(name="DESC")
        private String desc;

        @Column(name="Price")
        private BigDecimal price;

        @Column(name="Tax")
        private BigDecimal tax;

        @Column(name="Shipping")
        private BigDecimal ship;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public int getDept() {
            return dept;
        }

        public void setDept(int dept) {
            this.dept = dept;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }

        public BigDecimal getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public BigDecimal getTax() {
            return tax;
        }

        public void setTax(BigDecimal tax) {
            this.tax = tax;
        }

        public BigDecimal getShip() {
            return ship;
        }

        public void setShip(BigDecimal ship) {
            this.ship = ship;
        }


    }
```